# Client-side validation of form in rails 3?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, live

I installed the [gem client_side_validations](https://github.com/dnclabs/client_side_validations), did everything exactly according to the manual, for greater certainty, I checked it on a test project, it worked, but when i migrate it to my project it gave this error:

```
 undefined method `validate_options' for #<User:0xb67365fc>
```

this is the form code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :validations => true, :html => {:id => 'commentform'}) do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :name, :label => t('general.name') %>
   <%= f.input :last_name, :label => t('general.last_name') %>
   <%= f.input :email, :label => t('general.email') %>
   <%= f.input :phone, :label => t('general.phone') %>
   <% if @user.password_required? %>
       <%= f.input :password, :label => t('general.password') %>
       <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :label => t('general.password_confirm') %>
       <%= f.hidden_field :is_anonym, :value => false %>
   <% end %>
   <br/>
   <%= f.button :submit, :label => t('general.button') %>
<% end %>
```

anyone help me..

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth I've rewritten the ClientSideValidation gem completely. The previous version I wrote at the DNC had some pretty big issues.

Feel free to check out the 3.0 rewrite: https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations